# How to set a web service on AMAZON (AWS) which is running a NODEJS server?

Tags: mysql, web-services, node.js, networking, amazon-web-services

*How to set up the connection between client (eg:MY Mobile browser) and the AWS Server which is running NODE server on it?*

- Is Web service is required?
- If so which one?
- How to set up the web service?

A code snippet of setting a simple web-service would help me

Comment: This is way, way, way too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use NODEJS or EXPressJS get the server running !**

Then use something like

```
http://Serverip::port
```

to access from your mobile

*that should work*